# New files in Android image get "Permission denied"

Tags: android, linux, permissions

I am trying to create a custom system partition:

I've extracted original system.img, mounted to a directory in host, added some new files with 777 permission mode, and then packed again, and flashed the new system image.

Yet, the files get "Permission denied".

I made several trials, but the same result.

It also seems that the structure of directories in the mounted system.img, is not the same as seen with adb shell. 
For example, there is no /system folder in the mounted system, yet with "adb shell" there is /system".

I am not sure what is the reason for this, and I am not familiar with it from normal Linux distributions.

**EDIT1:**

See the ranranX files below as created in the image:

```
....
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 136948 2009-01-01 10:00 NOTICE.html.gz
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    148 2009-01-01 10:00 oem-default.prop
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    151 2009-01-01 10:00 oem-vz.prop
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 657938 2009-01-01 10:00 old-apns-conf.xml
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 2009-01-01 10:00 permissions
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 2009-01-01 10:00 ppp
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  76790 2009-01-01 10:00 preloaded-classes
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  16384 2009-01-01 10:00 qcril.db
**-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root      0 2016-11-16 20:08 ranran1
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root  75340 2016-11-16 20:08 ranran2**
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 749737 2009-01-01 10:00 recovery-resource.dat
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  10524 2009-01-01 10:00 regulatory_info_lgw200a.png
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   5729 2009-01-01 10:00 regulatory_info_lgw200e.png
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  10524 2009-01-01 10:00 regulatory_info_lgw200n.png
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  34058 2009-01-01 10:00 regulatory_info_lgw200.png
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  10519 2009-01-01 10:00 regulatory_info_lgw200v.png
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    925 2009-01-01 10:00 sec_config
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   4096 2009-01-01 10:00 security
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 2009-01-01 10:00 sensors
```

While with adb shell, when doing ls -al I see them as "Permission denied" (without -al they appear without this error):

```
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2009-01-01 10:00 permissions
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2009-01-01 10:00 ppp
-rw-r--r-- root     root        76790 2009-01-01 10:00 preloaded-classes
-rw-r--r-- root     root        16384 2009-01-01 10:00 qcril.db
lstat './ranran1' failed: Permission denied
lstat './ranran2' failed: Permission denied
-rw-r--r-- root     root       749737 2009-01-01 10:00 recovery-resource.dat
-rw-r--r-- root     root        34058 2009-01-01 10:00 regulatory_info_lgw200.png
-rw-r--r-- root     root        10524 2009-01-01 10:00 regulatory_info_lgw200a.png
-rw-r--r-- root     root         5729 2009-01-01 10:00 regulatory_info_lgw200e.png
```

Thank you,
Ranchu

Comment: Yet, you need to remount the `/system` partition with `rw`. Under root execute: `mount -o rw,remount /system`.

Comment: I have edited the question and added information.  I have created a new system.img which I then flashed into device, so I don't understand what's the difference between my new files the other files in the same directory.